# How do I dissolve repeating data and add a column to my data frame summing the quantity dissolved in r?

Tags: r, merge, datatable, plyr, organization

I need help on how to dissolve multiple columns based on a commonality in r, and also adding a new column to the data frame that reflects the quantity dissolved. I didn't include in the mock data below, but the y and z data are different in every column. I have hundreds of rows too.

```
#My data now

x  y  z  

A
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
B
B
C
C
C
C
C

#How I want my data to look
x  y  z  q

A        4
B        6
C        5
```

Comment: I think you need `table(df1$x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to group, then count the number of entries within each group and place into a new column using `summarise`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(q = n())
```

Comment: very welcome - can you accept the answer if this is what you used please?